# How to switch between components in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

[image]

Above is the picture of my program. I used JTextField, JTextArea and JTable to create my program. What I want to do, is to allow user to press "tab" to switch between the 4 different components. However, when it reaches the JTable called "Deadlines and Time Task", "tab" will just switch between cells. What I want is to make "tab" switch to the table below instead.

The reason is to allow my program to support the use of keyboard to scroll the table. Else, I can't scroll the table below using keyboard.

Comment: `The reason is to allow my program to support the use of keyboard to scroll the table` - this is already supported. Use PageUp and PageDown to scroll one page at a time or use the Up and Down arrows to scroll one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use your own custom Focus Traversal Policy.
Here you have link to [How to Use Focus Subsystem Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

and the section that you are interested in is "Customizing Focus Traversal"

The live demo presented there, presents exact behaviour you are need (tabbing between tables, not between cells)